# How to Install Ubuntu on Toshiba Satellite Click Mini L9W-B-100 Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have a 32 bit iso of Ubuntu Kylin from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-kylin. I have burnt this to a formatted usb drive using rufus-2.11 with settings: 
Partition scheme and target system type: MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI
File system: Large FAT32
Cluster Size: 32 kilobytes

I have then created a bootable disk using ISO image and selected my ubuntukylin-16.04.1-desktop-i386.

I then tested this with my desktop pc and managed to boot to ubuntu using it fine.

I then inserted this in my Toshiba Satellite Click Mini L9W-B-100 and there is no option to boot from this. I disabled secure boot in the BIOS as others online suggested but this does not help.

I then attempted to install Ubuntu Kylin with unetbootin to the hard drive, trying to boot from this however just gives the error message that the file \ubnldr.mbr is missing
status: 0xc000007b

Any help would be greatly appreciated.